# Haskell: Yesod and state

Tags: haskell, state, yesod, acid

I was reading through the code for a [Toy URL Shortener](http://flygdynamikern.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/toy-url-shortener-with-yesod-and-acid.html). However, there's significant parts I just can't get my head around.

It has the following code:

```
data URLShort = URLShort { state :: AcidState URLStore }
```

For testing purposes, I wrote something like this in my own app:

```
data MyApp = MyApp { state :: Int }
```

I could then compile by changing

```
main = warpDebug 3000 MyApp
```

to

```
main = warpDebug 3000 (MyApp 42)
```

And I could then do reads of the state in handlers by doing

```
mystate <- fmap state getYesod
```

inspired by `acid <- fmap state getYesod` in the article. However, I didn't know how to do writes.

I have also tried doing:

```
data MyApp = MyApp { state :: State Int Int }
```

But I didn't get far with this.

I was trying to work out how `AcidState` works just by doing some simple similar examples, figuring that since `AcidState` keeps everything in memory, I should be able to do the same?

Any sort of general explanation of what is going on here, and also perhaps how I'm missing the point would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `AcidState a` data type is not an immutable value all the way down; it contains references to mutable data internally. What is stored in Yesod-land in this case is simply an immutable reference to this data. When you update the state, you don't actually update the value in the foundation data type, but instead the memory that it points to.

Every value in the Haskell world is immutable. However, a lot of things outside of the Realm of Haskell isn't immutable; for example, when you do `putStrLn`, the terminal mutates its display to show new content. The `putStrLn` action itself is an immutable pure value, but it *describes* how to perform an action involving mutation.

There are other functions that also yield actions that perform mutations; if you do `ref <- newIORef 0`, you get a value describing an action that creates a mutable memory cell. If you then do `modifyIORef ref (+1)`, you get a value describing an action that increments the value in that cell by `1`. The `ref` value is a *pure value*, it's simply a reference to a mutable cell. The code is also *purely functional*, because each piece only describes an action; nothing is mutable *within the Haskell program*.

This is how `AcidState` implements its state: by using a system that manages state outside of the Haskell world. This is not "as bad as" having full mutability like in languages such as C, because in Haskell, you can *control the mutability* with the power of monads. Using `AcidState` is perfectly safe and does not involve the use of `unsafePerformIO` as far as I know.

With `AcidState` in this case, you use `openAcidState emptyStore` in the `IO` monad to create a new acid state (that line is a value describing an IO action that opens a new acid state). You use `createCheckpointAndClose` to optionally save the acid state to disk safely. Finally, you use the `update'` function to mutate the contents of an acid state.

To create a "small state" yourself using `IORef`s (The simplest form of mutable state, except for maybe the `ST` monad), you first add a field like this to your foundation data type:

```
data VisitorCounter = VisitorCounter { visitorCounter :: IORef Int }
```

You then do:

```
main = do
  counter <- newIORef 0
  warpDebug 3000 (VisitorCounter counter)
```

In a handler, you can modify the counter like this:

```
counter <- fmap visitorCounter getYesod
modifyIORef counter (+1)
count <- readIORef counter
-- ... display the count or something
```

Note the symmetry to `AcidState`.

For a site counter, I would actually recommend using [`TVar`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html#TVar) instead of `IORef`s, because of the possibility that multiple clients might modify the variable simultaneously. The interface to `TVar`s is very similar, however.

---

**Follow up question from question author?**

I've placed `{ visitorCounter :: TVar Int }` in my foundation type, and the following code in the handler:

```
counter <- fmap visitorCounter getYesod
count <- readTVar counter
```

The first line compiles fine, but the second throws this error:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `GHandler sub0 Middleware t0'
>             with actual type `STM a0'
> In the return type of a call of `readTVar'
> In a stmt of a 'do' expression: count <- readTVar counter
> ```

How could I fix this?

Comment: I don't really understand this. I thought all data in Haskell was immutable, even Monads, as the "do notation" is just syntactic sugar for functional code.

If this data is "secretly" mutable, isn't a chance that Haskell, by assuming everything is immutable, won't return a modified value (because it will assume it is unchanged).

You seem to be suggesting it works like "unsafePerformIO". Is that really the case?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please comment if you still have questions.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Follow-up question: Can you provide an implementation of a trivial version of something like "IORef" or "TVar", just so I can see what they're doing (it seems like black magic at the moment)? I'd also like some information about thread safety, but I think it would be best for me to read through your answer first regarding implementation details.

Comment: `IORef` is black magic. I cannot provide an implementation, as much as I cannot show how `putStrLn` or `Int` is implemented. The source is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-IORef.html#IORef), but it is hardly informative; IO references are primitive in Haskell, so everything just redirects to GHC internals. Same goes for `TVar`; it uses GHC internals to achieve software-transactional memory.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Could you please give an example using TVar?

Comment: Please see my followup question in the edit to your post, I'm having trouble using TVar.

Comment: I got this working using `liftIO`. i.e. `count <- liftIO $ readTVarIO counter`