# Keeping state around in Yesod

Tags: haskell, state, yesod

I'm trying to implement a Pachisi-like boardgame with Yesod. Currently, the Haskell code receives the current state of the board via Ajax, does some stuff with it (e.g. calculate if a new piece can enter the board, whether the game ends and so on) and returns it as JSON that the client can use to update the view.

In effect, I'm keeping state in the client to circumvent the problem that Haskell has no mutability. In other languages I'd probably declare a variable `gameState` and have server-side code modify it before returning it to the client, but in Haskell... I may be missing something entirely; I'm far from experienced when it comes to Haskell.

I want to do as little as possible client-side since this is supposed to be an exercise in haskelling. I've found [Haskell: Yesod and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007497/haskell-yesod-and-state) but couldn't really make sense of it. So the question remains: is there any better way to handle the game state than my solution?

Comment: Yes, there are better ways to do that. For example, you can keep pretty much all of the client state in a database and retrieve/change it upon a clients request (get would only require an ID, post an ID  + changeset). [`persistent`](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) is the "default" way to do this with `Yesod`, but you can roll your own solution or use something else if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy. Yesod's machinery spins around a data type called `Foundation`. In scaffolding this data type has the same name, even.

What you need to do is to extend this data type with a record representing your state, `MVar YourState`, for instance.

Now, in `Handler` actions you can use `y <- getYesod` to get the Foundation value, extract a MVar out of it and use/modify it at your will.